# Is this magic square solvable with no more information?

Tags: magic-square

This magic square question was given to my brothers sixth grader:

```
-------------------
| 122 |     | 126 |
-------------------
| 129 |     |     |
-------------------
|     |     |     |
-------------------
```

This is literally all the information that was given to the kids. So it's not a typical 1-9 magic square, but I don't see how we can guess what range it is. And without knowing the sum, I honestly haven't got the idea how to solve this. If I were to assume that the range of values is 121-129 it's solvable, but is there some reason why we should assume that that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the magic square be represented as $\begin{pmatrix}122 & a&126 \\ 129 &b &c \\ d& e & f\end{pmatrix}$.

From $122+129 + d = 126 + b + d$ we get $b=125$. We find this by searching for a row/column/diagonal were we have a lot of information already. Knowing $b$ we can continue $122+b+f=126+c+f \Longrightarrow 122+b=126+c \Longrightarrow c = 121 $. Know we also now the sum of all colums/rows/diagonals via $129+b+c = 375$. And now everything follows immediately:
\begin{align}
&a = 375-122-126 = 127 \\
&d = 375-122-129 = 124 \\
&f = 375-126-121 = 128 \\
&e = 375-124-128 = 123
\end{align}
And the final result is:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
122 & 127 & 126 \\
129 & 125 & 121 \\
124 & 123 & 128
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

It is even solvable for 6th graders to train solving linear equations but I think it is not an easy question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the element in the lower left. Then the magic sum $S$ is $251+x$. But the $S$ is also $(3/2)(126+x)$ because the central element of a $3×3$ square must be the average of any two elements that are $180°$ apart. So

$251+x=(3/2)(126+x)=189+(3/2)x$

$x=124$

$S=251+124=(3/2)(126+124)=375$

The rest should then follow smoothly.